# Random walk on the natural Expectation

Tags: probability

Let's consider a random walk on the natural numbers $(1,2,3...)$, where we always go from $1$ to $2$ and otherwise to the left with probability $p$, hence to the right with probability $1-p$.

I aim to find the number of expected steps until the number $n$ is reached for the first time. Does there exist any solution without using generating functions?

Thanks in advance for any piece of information.

Cassius Manuel

Comment: If you go to the left when you are on zero, what happens? Do you go to -1, which is outside the set of natural numbers? Or do you just stay on zero? Or is 1 the lower bound, and zero is unreachable?

Comment: Denote with $h_k$ the expected number of steps to reach $n$ when you are in state $k$ for $k\ge 1$. Then $$\begin{cases}h_1=1+h_2\\h_k=1+ph_{k-1}+(1-p)h_{k+1}, & \text{for } 3\le k\le n-1\\h_n=0\end{cases}$$ Can you solve the recurrence relation to obtain a  closed form for $h_k$?

Comment: Indeed, that's an effective way to prove it, as I have just checked. There is a little typo without importance, it is k runs from 2 to n-1, not from 3. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1):

For organization, I'm turning [Stef's comment](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1035085/random-walk-on-the-natural-expectation#comment2110358_1035085) into an answer:

> Denote with $h_k$ the expected number of steps to reach $n$ when you are in state $k$ for $k \geq 1$. Then: $$\begin{cases}h_1=1+h_2\\h_k=1+ph_{k-1}+(1-p)h_{k+1}, & \text{for } 3\le k\le n-1\\h_n=0\end{cases}$$Can you solve the recurrence relation to obtain a closed form for $h_k$?